# EpPlus, c# Add CommandButton to WorkSheet

Tags: c#, epplus

i'm using Epplus 4.1 and i want to add a commandbutton object to my WorkSheet using dynamicly.

Is there someone who have a solution

Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have tried. This is not a code writing site. See here for how to provide a [MCVE] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the deley,
Below the code,

```
  Dim fi As New FileInfo("E:\test_XL.xlsx")
  If fi.Exists Then fi.Delete()
  Dim _pck As New ExcelPackage(fi)
  Dim ws = _pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName)
  'I want to add a commandButton in this WorkSheet
```